# Java syntax " ... = () -> {...}"

Tags: java, syntax

Recently I was looking at the http://winterbe.com/posts/2015/04/07/java8-concurrency-tutorial-thread-executor-examples/ tutorial and he uses the following syntax.

```
Runnable task = () -> {
    String threadName = Thread.currentThread().getName();
    System.out.println("Hello " + threadName);
};

task.run();

Thread thread = new Thread(task);
thread.start();

System.out.println("Done!");
```

I deducted that instead of using "... = -> () {...}" which I don't fully understand (did not find any documentation related to this syntax) I could create a class in the following way:

```
public class IAmRunnable1 implements Runnable {

  @Override
  public void run() {
    String threadName = Thread.currentThread().getName();
    System.out.println("Hello " + threadName);

  }

}
```

And use this class in my code as shown below:

```
//ref:http://winterbe.com/posts/2015/04/07/java8-concurrency-tutorial-thread-executor-examples/
public class ExecutorRunnableExample {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    Runnable task = new IAmRunnable1();

  task.run();

  Thread thread = new Thread(task);
  thread.start();

  System.out.println("Done!");

  }

}
```

Can someone direct me to the documentation related to this syntax or give me an appropriate explanation.

Thanks!

Comment: Search for lambda expressions (introduced in Java 8)

Comment: I really think Java8 has destroyed programming standards.

Answer (score 4):

This is the syntax for Java 8 lambdas. In essence:

```
Runnable r = () -> { ... }
```

is the same as

```
Runnable r = new Runnable() { public void run() {  ... } }
```

Comment: Note that you can only use lambdas with "functional interfaces." These interfaces will only have ONE method. i.e. `Runnable`'s only method is `run()`, so this is what is called.

Comment: So in `()->{...}` what `()` represents? Arguments I need to pass to `new Runnable` or arguments of `run()`?

Comment: () is the arguments passed to the method; in this case, run() takes no arguments. See Java 8 language documentation for the full syntax rules.

Comment: I actually know that, but example in your answer contains two `()` which may be confusing for someone new to subject. Could you add that information to your answer (I tried to do so with my previous edit but it seems you didn't like it for some reason).

Comment: Thanks for all your answers, i did not knew it was called Java lambda.

Comment: I am not a big fan of Java lambdas, maybe it is just me but I find them a bit unreadable